# How to setup Ember-CLI project with Swagger-Client to use DreamFactory REST services

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-cli, swagger

I'm trying to setup an Ember-CLI app to use [DreamFactory](http://dreamfactory.com).

I'm using:

- ember-cli 0.2.0-beta.1
- DreamFactory 1.9.0
- emberjs 1.10.0

I've tries to import `swagger-client` and `shred.bundle` through `Brocfile` but this causes an error that `app-boot.js` is unable to find the module `<app_name>/app`.

If I remove `swagger-client` and `shred.bundle`, it loads fine.

How can I import `swagger` and make it available to the Ember app?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you make it work?

Comment: @Bhoomi, sadly I wasn't, I moved away from DreamFactory and now use Elixir/Phoenix for the backend services.